# Error: Incorrect string value: 'xF0\xA9\xB5\x8B' for column 'name' at row 1

Tags: mysql, string

Getting the above error message when I run a php script in windows using the command prompt. I am using mySQL version 6.3. Character and collation settings for mySQL are as follows:

[Character and collation settings image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2hWYi.png)

As you can see from the above image, all settings apart from the collation_connection are unicode_ci, and character sets are utf8mb4 other than system. Other steps I have already taken:

1. Checked and double checked that all my columns with the name 'name' in my table are using the right character set and collation - utf8mb4 and utf8mb4_unicode_ci respectively; all are fine.
2. Added the following lines in my my.ini file under the mysql section:

   ```
   default-character-set=utf8mb4
   ```

and the following lines under mysqld:

```
character-set-server=utf8mb4
collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
init_connect='SET NAMES utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci'
```

3. Also made sure that the configuration file in Workbench is the same one I have been editing.
4. SQL mode is set to:

   ```
   sql-mode="STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
   ```
5. Have obviously restarted :P

Can anyone think what else it could be? Been stuck on this for a while now :(

Comment: `0xF0A9B58B` seems like valid utf8(mb4) encoding for the character  based on http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/29d4b/index.htm... but there's no such thing as MySQL Server 6.3... please run the query `SELECT @@VERSION, @@VERSION_COMMENT;` to confirm your MySQL Server version.

Comment: Ah yes, sorry. I have version 5.7.21-log, with version comment MySQL Community Server (GPL).

Comment: You should be able to test with a simple query like `INSERT INTO t1 (name) VALUES (UNHEX('F0A9B58B'));` then select it back and see the right character.  If that insert works, then MySQL is accepting it at the table, so the trouble is further out.  If not, there's something not right about the table.

Comment: Thanks Michael. I tried this, but received the error 'ERROR 1364 (HY000): Field 'realname' doesn't have a default value'. Interestingly this happened when I entered data for the column 'name', not 'realname', and then the opposite happened when I inserted data into column 'realname'. After some Google searching, seems removing strict mode would solve it, or setting a default value for the columns such as '0', but I'm not really too keen on those since wouldn't this mean lots of names would just appear as '0' if they didn't enter correctly?

Comment: Yeah, don't remove strict mode.  Just modify the query to insert values into all of the `NOT NULL` columns -- that's what the `doesn't have a default value` error means -- an insert statement must supply a value for all columns that are not nullable.